# How to update the folder property in sharepoint shareddocument folder

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, properties, directory

Below C# code I have used to update the folder property in shared document, same concept I have tried in PowerShell but I didn't get any clue.

```
SPFolder newFolder = folders.Add(ParentURL + FolderURL + "/" + FolderName);
//Added Title Property to newFolder
newFolder.AddProperty("vti_title", FolderName);
//newFolder.Update();
```

In PowerShell:

```
> $web = Get-SPWeb "http://server/sites/4tmdk9h7qc4g"
> $site=$web $list = $web.Lists["Shared Documents"] 
  foreach ($item in $list.Folders)
  { 
    write-host $item["Title"] 
    /?? HOW TO UPDATE HERE
    $item.Update() 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Finally this code loop all the site document folder and updated the title


$inputUrl =Read-Host "Enter the site URL" 
$site = Get-SPSite -identity $inputUrl 
$site | Get-SPWeb -limit |ForEach-Object 
{   
$web = Get-SPWeb $_.Url     
$list =$web.lists["Shared Documents"]   
Write-Host $_.Url   
foreach($item in $list.folders)     
{  
$item["Title"]="ayyappan"
$item.update()
Write-Host $item["Title"] 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$item is a SPListItem object. Use SPListItem.Folder to access the SPFolder object:

```
$item.Folder
```